# cloned select <option> changes the first select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's my code for cloning the select option:

```
var clone = $('#saleTable tbody>tr#saleTR:last').clone(true);
            clone.find("input").val('');
            clone.insertAfter('#saleTable tbody>tr#saleTR:last');
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<tr id="saleTR">
  <td>
    <input name="qty[]" type="text" size="5" />
  </td>
  <td> 
    <select name="description[]" onchange="showPrice(this.value)">
      <option value="null">select Item sold</option>
      <?php getSaleItem(); ?>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span id="price"></span>
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I'm using ajax to display the prices:

```
function showPrice(str){
    if (str.length==0){ 
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("price").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getPrice.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

The `<tr>` is cloned fine but when the last cloned select option is selected or changed, the first price is the one that keeps on changing not the corresponding price i.e the first original price keeps changing instead of the one corresponding in-line with the select option change.

I want a particular select option to update the corresponding price.

Comment: When you clone element, clone get same ID. IDs must be unique for all elements of same document

Comment: please illustrate it for me

Comment: Might I suggest `<tr class="saleTR">` instead of `<tr id="saleTR">` and `<span class="price">` instead of `<span id="price">`

Answer (score 0):

In your html you can pass this object to your ajax function and than you can use this pointer to select your corrosponding price span.

This may work for you

HTML

```
<tr id="saleTR">
    <td>
        <input name="qty[]" type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="description[]" onchange="showPrice(this)">
            <option value="null">select Item sold</option>
            <?php getSaleItem(); ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><span id="price"></span>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function showPrice(selectBox) {
    var str = selectBox.value;
    var corSpan=$(selectBox).closest('#saleTR').find('#price');
    if (str.length == 0) {
        corSpan.html() = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            corSpan.html(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getPrice.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

see similar example [http://jsfiddle.net/Yamw6/](http://jsfiddle.net/Yamw6/1/)

Comment: That must work . please check your code once again , make sure in onchange function you are passing this. check similar example at http://jsfiddle.net/Yamw6/1/

Comment: but how can i sum up all the span value i used this code   $('select.description').change(function(){
   var tot= $('#saleTable tbody tr#totalTR');
   var prices ='';
   $('#price').each(function(){
    var add = +$('#price:last').text();
    prices += add;
   });
   tot.find('.totalPrice').html(prices);
  });

Comment: As .text() return string format so first you need to convert it into int(parseInt) or float(parseFloat) numbers to do mathematical operation. Try
 $('select.description').change(function () {
    var tot = $('#saleTable tbody tr#totalTR');
    var prices = '';
    $('#price').each(function () {
        var add = parseInt($(this).text());
        prices += add;
    });
    tot.find('.totalPrice').html(prices);
});

Comment: hi sudhanshu, i did as you said, it just pick the first span value and display it,that 1) it is not displaying the current selected price rather the previous price selected. 2)it is not adding all the prices inas to display on the amount space. sorry am just new in javascript

Comment: i just add span to the span id name, $('select.description').change(function(){
   var tot= $('#saleTable tbody tr#totalTR');
   var prices ='';
   $('span#price').each(function(){
    
    var add = parseInt($(this).text());
    prices += add;
   });
   tot.find('.totalPrice').html(prices);
  }); and it display the values but it is been display    as if it is in an array secondly it pick the pre-value to calculate the total not the one been selected

Comment: It is picking pre value because you are adding it before new value came to price span as it is ajax it will take time to update new value . So keep your addition logic itself inside ajax call after you updated the new value  to price span(after corSpan.html(xmlhttp.responseText);).

Comment: this is how my code is but not good:
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
       
    corSpan.html(xmlhttp.responseText);
    $('select.description').change(function(){
     var tot= $('#saleTable tbody tr#totalTR');
     var prices ='';
     $('span#price').each(function(){
      var check = parseInt($(this).text());
      var add = parseInt($(this).text(),10);
      prices += add;
    
    });
     tot.find('.totalPrice').html(prices);
    });
      }

Comment: inside that dont give change event as that event is already triggered. just use

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){ if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){ corSpan.html(xmlhttp.responseText); var tot= $('#saleTable tbody tr#totalTR'); var prices =''; $('span#price').each(function(){ var check = parseInt($(this).text()); var add = parseInt($(this).text(),10); prices += add; }); tot.find('.totalPrice').html(prices);  }

Comment: ok it is work but the total is displaying 100150100 when adding instead of 350 as the total

Comment: ok,the problem was that it see the price as string, thanks Sudhanshu you are really appreciated by me

Comment: hey Sudhanshu how can i get the corresponding value of the input text field